# How to prevent tooltip going off screen

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip

Need help im making tooltip not going off screen. I've tried this, but it doen't because e.pageX and e.pageY is giving me the real position related to page width and height, not to window width and height.

```
$(".content .people .photo-show").hover(function() {
        var image = $(this).attr('image');
        $('<div class="photo"><img src="' + image + '"></div>').appendTo('body').fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $('.photo').remove();
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20 + 'px';
        var mousey = e.pageY - 20 + 'px';

        if ((mousey + $('.photo').outerHeight()) >= $(window).height()) {
        mousey = e.pageY - $('.photo').outerHeight();
        console.log('did it');
        }
        $('.photo').css({ 'top': mousey, 'left': mousex });
    });
```